# searching using a ListView with options

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `ListView` which gets data directly from the database. I want to use it to search for a record using any of the variables, i.e. name, number, or location. Currently I am able to search but using only one variable.

This is my code:

```
public void searchlist()
{
    if (searchbox.Text != "")
    {
        for (int i = listView1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var item = listView1.Items[i];
            if (item.Text.Contains(searchbox.Text))
            {
                item.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
                item.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
            }
            else
            {
                listView1.Items.Remove(item);
            }
        }
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
        {
            listView1.Focus();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        loadthelist();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Currently I am able to search but using only one variable."_ What does this mean? Which variable? Note also that this is a statement, not a question. Obviously you want to be able to search by all variables, not just one, but what exactly do you need help with? It would also help to know what `listView.Items` contains btw.

Comment: As far as I can understand from your question, the thing that you want is to be able to search on multiple variables. But how do you want that to be, all from the same input box and search that value on all columns? An input for each column and have multiple search values that have to be matched? what exactly is it that is the desired result and  what have you tried?

Comment: You're possibly looking for the SubItems (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems(v=vs.110).aspx) collection if you want to walk through all of the other column values and test them against the search text. As the other comments have indicated, it isn't clear from the question exactly what you're after though.

Comment: @stakx i am using the first column of the listview to search for a record in the listview,my question is how can i have a combobox which contains all the columns so that when one needs to seach he choose the column then enter the value in a textbox

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need this:

```
private class TestClass
    {
        public int Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Detail
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    private void ListViewSearch_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<TestClass> source = new List<TestClass>();
        source.Add(new TestClass { Id = 1, Text = "one", Detail = "D1" });
        source.Add(new TestClass { Id = 2, Text = "two", Detail = "D2" });
        source.Add(new TestClass { Id = 3, Text = "three", Detail = "D1" });
        source.Add(new TestClass { Id = 4, Text = "four", Detail = "D3" });
        source.Add(new TestClass { Id = 5, Text = "five", Detail = "D6" });
        source.Add(new TestClass { Id = 6, Text = "5", Detail = "D6" });

        listView1.Columns.Add("Id");
        listView1.Columns.Add("Text");
        listView1.Columns.Add("Detail");

        source.ForEach(x =>
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(x.Id.ToString());
            item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
            item.SubItems.Add(x.Text);
            item.SubItems.Add(x.Detail);
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        });

        listView1.View = View.Details;

        listView1.GridLines = true;



        comboBox1.DataSource = listView1.Columns;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Text";

    }

    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {
                for (int subItemIndex = 0; subItemIndex < item.SubItems.Count; subItemIndex++)
                {
                    if (subItemIndex == comboBox1.SelectedIndex && item.SubItems[subItemIndex].Text.Contains(textBox1.Text))
                    {
                        item.SubItems[subItemIndex].BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
                        item.SubItems[subItemIndex].ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item.SubItems[subItemIndex].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                        item.SubItems[subItemIndex].ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```